# Running PyGears framework on Windows

Tags: pygears

I just started using pyGears and I find it easier working on Windows. I was wondering is it possible to run it on Windows or it's only Linux based?

Answer (score 1):

It can maybe be run on Windows but I wouldn't count on it for now. PyGears is natively supporting Linux (Ubuntu) so if you have a choice I would advise switching to Ubuntu.

There is a future plan for supporting PyGears for Windows in a full manner, but at the moment that's not the priority.